# Corona Simulator stop working after connecting to server

Tags: python, lua, coronasdk, twisted

I have 2 server file work with corona simulator. One is work but another isn't. Not sure what is the different between these 2 file. Below is my server code.

Non-working:

```
class Chat(Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        self.factory.clients.append(self)
    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        self.factory.clients.remove(self)
    def dataReceived(self,data):
        for c in self.factory.clients:
            c.message(data)
            print data
    def message(self, data):
        self.transport.write(data)

factory = Factory()
factory.clients = []
factory.protocol = Chat

reactor.listenTCP(8080,factory)
reactor.run()
```

Working:

```
class IphoneChat(Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        self.factory.clients.append(self)
        print "Clients are " ,self.factory.clients
    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        self.factory.clients.remove(self)
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        print "The data is " ,data
        for c in self.factory.clients:
            c.message(data)
    def message(self, message):
        self.transport.write(message + '\n')

factory = Factory()
factory.clients = []
factory.protocol = IphoneChat
reactor.listenTCP(8080, factory)
print "Server Start!!!"
reactor.run()
```

I put all of my code because I afraid of missing something important about the code.
Thank you for incoming help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send "\n" at the end of message

```
class Chat(Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        self.factory.clients.append(self)
    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        self.factory.clients.remove(self)
    def dataReceived(self,data):
        for c in self.factory.clients:
            c.message(data)
            print data
    def message(self, data):
        self.transport.write(data + '\n')

factory = Factory()
factory.clients = []
factory.protocol = Chat

reactor.listenTCP(8080,factory)
reactor.run()
```

Its HTTP protocol requirement.

Comment: I just know. Thank you very much. :D

Comment: Hi iBad, I tried using Ruby server instead of Python. Is ruby have something like the requirement? I used puts "aaa" but seem to have the same problem.

Comment: Hi, its protocol requirement, doesn't depend on language. Corona client is just sitting there and waiting for '\n'

Comment: I tried adding \n in puts method but it still doesn't work. Here is my code is Ruby https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706661/ruby-why-my-server-is-stop-working