# Ruby -- Why my server is stop working

Tags: ruby, sockets, lua, coronasdk

I wrote my app that use Lua and connect to my server using Ruby but when the application start, it seem stop working. I'm not sure what the problem is because I'm new to Ruby but I ever used Python and have the same problem [Corona Simulator stop working after connecting to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25702204/corona-simulator-stop-working-after-connecting-to-server/25702347#25702347)

I'm curious is Ruby have something like http protocol requirement or not? Below is my code using puts to send data to client.

```
require "socket"
class Server
    def initialize(ip,port)
        puts "Server Start!!"
        @server = TCPServer.open(ip,port)
        @connections = Hash.new
        @rooms = Hash.new
        @clients = Hash.new
        @connections[:server] = @server
        @connections[:rooms] = @rooms
        @connections[:clients] = @clients
    end

    def run
        loop {
            Thread.start(@server.accept) do |client|
                puts "New client connected."
                nickname = client.gets.chomp.to_sym

                puts "#{nickname} #{client}"
                @connections[:clients][nickname] = client
                client.puts "Hi there"
                client.print "\n"
                client.close
            end
        }.join
    end
end

server = Server.new("127.0.0.1",8080)
server.run
```

Answer (score 0):

add

```
client.print "\n
client.close
```

at the end of thread function and it should work

Comment: Still doesn't work. I have updated the code in the post. Is it what you mean?